# import of gitlab issues from CSV using quick actions fails for labels with white space

Tags: csv, gitlab

This works fine for me for simply one-word labels with CSV like this:

```
"title";"description"
"issue title";"some description goes here
/assign @akos
/label ~stackoverflow ~waiting"
```

Need to add some label like `Feature: Something` and it fails, due to whitespace.
Couldn't find out of the docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html how to tackle it.

already gave a try to:

- `/label Feature: Something`
- `/label Feature:+Something`
- `/label Feature:%20Something`
- `/label "Feature: Something"`
- `/label "Feature:\sSomething"`
- `/label "Feature:&nbsp;Something"`

with no luck

Answer (score 0):

figure it out

crucial thing - put your whitespaced label in 2x `""`

e.g label: **`Feature: Something`**
must be encoded **`~""Feature: Something""`**

the following CSV structure did the trick:

```
title,description
issue title,"
some description goes here

/label ~""Feature: Something""
/assign @akos 
"
```